# Some people can't access to my website that has a dot.tk domain and hosted on 1freehosting

Tags: web, web-hosting, domain-name

I get a free domain name at **dot.tk** and upload my website to 1freehosting, both tools are free, i can see my website on a mac, but i can't see it when surfing on a windows pc, i found that when disabling anti-phising feature of the antivirus i can see it, but... that shouldn't happen, that means that my website is recognized as phising... so what should i do?

- When a website is recognized as phising, what are the reasons?
- Is the problem the hosting?
- Is the problem de domain name server?

Comment: Its possible that IP of your free hosting server was added to database of "bad" servers, and antiviruses recognize it. Is there any ads that you free hosting puts to your website pages?

Comment: No, the server doesn't put adds to the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't find any information, but i resolve the problem using other free domain names, the one i used is .ml, there're other free and short domain names at: [FreeNom](http://www.freenom.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, from what I can see DNS servers for .tk and .gq are down. I see a twit saying the provider freenom is dead. Let's hope it's not true.

Comment: true... now i experiencing the same. Geeez....